# convert android device to touch screen interactive display with full features locked

Tags: android, interactive

```
I am trying to develop an interactive APP and want only that app to work none of the othrs or home button everything to be disabled even the power button. Is this possible?
```

The overall motive is to convert it to a touch screen display for the shops etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the app only should and remaining all should be disabled,but once after the mobile go to sleep after 1-2 min but at that time you need to press lock button na....

Comment: You may write a service to launch the APP whenever it was closed; Use the APP to keep the device awake; Use a physical shield to block customers access all physical buttons;

Comment: I think the best solution would be to use guest mode with only one app enabled everything else locked. even pressing home button will go to the app .   The power button can be hidden with physical coverage.